# Refresh the view from JQuery ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having a cshml view in which i am calling another view in a  div as follows

```
    <div class="family_name" id="DisplayPartilView">
        <div class="content_part content_part2">
         <h1 class="family_nameStyle">Additional Contacts  <button id="AddEmergencyContact" jid="@ViewData["offerId"].ToString()" class="btn highlight" data-dismiss="modal" >
                +</button></h1> 
            <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
            <div id="listChildContactAuthorisationsCI" class="table_form">
                <table style="width: 640px;" id="CIAuthtable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Name</td>
                         <td title="This contact is authorised to drop off and collect this child.">Collection</td>
                        <td title="This contact is an emergency contact for the child.">Emergency</td>
                        <td title="This contact can authorise the child to participate in centre excursions.">Excursion</td>
                        <td title="This contact can authorised the administering of medication to the child.">Medical</td>
                    </tr>
                    @if (Model.ChildContactAuthorisations != null)
                    {

                          @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ChildContactAuthorisations)
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

This view is shared among other view and so it is in Shared/Editor Template folder.
I am using the ajax from another page (addcontact) as follows

```
          $.ajax({
                data: $.parseJSON('{"Id" : "' + EntityId + '"}'),
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@(Url.Action("GetAdditionalContacts", "QkEnrolment"))',

                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.outerHTML);

                    $('div#listChildContactAuthorisationsCI').html(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                }
               });
```

The control is going to the controller following controller function after adding a contact

```
      public ActionResult GetAdditionalContacts(int Id)
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["offerId"]);
        User user = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICrud<User>>().Where(x => x.Username == WebSiteContext.Current.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
        var offer = _offerRepo.Get(Id);
        var child = _childRepo.Get(offer.Child.Id);
        var childStubContactAuthorisations = child.GetContactAuthorisations().ToList();

        List<Section_ChildContactAuthorisation> ChildContactAuthorisations1 = GetAggregateChildContactAuthorisations(user, childStubContactAuthorisations);

        TempData["offerId"] = Id;

       return Json(ChildContactAuthorisations1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

But   i want to update the view with the model(which contains newly added contact) return from this above controller function. But the view is not updating.

Can anybody please help me in this
Thanks,
Vidya

Comment: you are returning the `json` and expecting the `html` in the ajax success. may i know why?

Comment: I am doing this for the first time...by mistake this happened...Could you pls tell me which is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Now you are setting json as html in your $('div#listChildContactAuthorisationsCI') you will have to iterate through the returned json and create appropriate html from those values and then add these to your $('div#listChildContactAuthorisationsCI').html(data)
Example:

```
data = '';
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
   data += '<li>' + result.whateverIsInhere + '</li>';
}
```

If you don't know what's in your json use Console.Log(result) then use the developer tools (F12 in chrome) and see what's inside.

Comment: HI,i changed myajax call as follows

Comment: instead of debugger use Console.Log(data); then look inside the developper tools (F12 inside chrome for example) what you are getting back. Then use data["name"] to retrieve your value. And then set that data where you need it.